# How to catch exception if the destination mail id does not exist while sending mail through webform?

Tags: 7, webforms, emails

I'm sending mails on submission of a webform. The destination mail address is fetched from a custom email field in the form. On submitting, when the user enters a mail address, a custom mail would be sent to that email.

I want to catch the exception if the mail id doesn't exist or if email is not sent.

Comment: Did you tried hook_mail_alter hhttps://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7.x

Comment: i used it for altering subject and body.. but not for exception.. could you tell me how?

Comment: In your hook alter you can use drupal_mail to send the email, it take care of exceptions and it return a message if something happened take a look https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7.x

Comment: i'm sending mails via webform config itself and not using drupal_mail. i used mail_alter for changing subject based on a requirement and extended mailsystem for for html mails. But confused how to catch exception if the destination mailid is not a valid one.